# How to show a visual component from a service

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I have a class which inherit from `Service` class

```
public class IdentityService extends Service;
```

This class is running obviously like a service. I need from that class show some visual component, like a `Notification`. But for `Notification` I need a reference for `Context`.

I run that service from a main activity, but I only don't know how can I pass that context. In that main activity I do something like this in onCreate method

```
startService(new Intent(this, IdentityService.class));
```

How could I get it there?

Comment: cant you bind this service with some activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Activity and Service actually extend Context so you can simply use this as your Context within your Service.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(/* your notification */);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = /* your intent */;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, /* your content */, pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(/* id */, notification);
```

Comment: I didn't know that Activity and Service extended Context! Thank you very much!